# File-less WCF activation results in "zero application (non-infrastructure) endpoints..." exception

Tags: wcf, iis-7, .net-4.0

I've got a WCF service that's using file-less activation:

```
  <bindings>
     <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding transferMode="Streamed">
           <security mode="Transport"/>
        </binding>
     </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>

  <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
     <serviceActivations>
        <add relativeAddress="RulesService.svc"
             service="Big.Company.RulesService.Service, RulesService" />
     </serviceActivations>
  </serviceHostingEnvironment>
```

On some machines, I see the following exception:

> Service
>   'Big.Company.RulesService.Service' has
>   zero application (non-infrastructure)
>   endpoints. This might be because no
>   configuration file was found for your
>   application, or because no service
>   element matching the service name
>   could be found in the configuration
>   file, or because no endpoints were
>   defined in the service element.

As far as I can tell, `.svc` is correctly mapped to the .NET 4.0 activation module. The application is in the "ASP.NET v4.0" application pool, which is configured for .NET v4.0, using the integrated pipeline.

If I remove the Web.config file, I get a 404 error. If I rename the bin\RulesService.dll file, I get a 'service not found' exception.

What's wrong with it?

**Update:** It appears to be a problem when turning on SSL. If I connect using HTTPS, it's fine, *until I turn on 'Require SSL' in IIS*.

Comment: Is your hosting AppPool configured to use .NET 4.0? This will be the most probably a problem of not using .NET 4.0 on your new environment.

Comment: Still haven't got this to work. Re-imaged the test box and changed the minimum requirements for the product...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An afternoon of using Reflector led me to the `ConfigLoader.AddDefaultEndpoints` method, which looks at the `ProtocolMappingSection` of the config file to work out which default endpoints to add.

It appears that HTTPS doesn't set up this section implicitly.

I solved it (with a hint from [something I'd seen earlier in the day](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article1026-new-features-in-wcf-40-part-2.aspx)) by adding the following to my Web.config file:

```
<protocolMapping>
   <add scheme="https" binding="basicHttpBinding"/>
   <add scheme="http" binding="basicHttpBinding"/>
</protocolMapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had only an HTTPS binding in IIS for my service and adding an http binding solved my problem. Without any file configuration.

[image: Add Http binding]

(Sorry for the french screenshot
)

Adding the following to the config file and removing the http binding in IIS also solved my problem.

```
<protocolMapping>
   <add scheme="https" binding="basicHttpBinding"/>
</protocolMapping>
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the identical problem at work and it was a permissions issue.